# 3-Way Modal in Telerik

Tags: telerik, modal-dialog

Good day!

I just wish to ask if any of you have a way to Open a modal from a modal, then from that second modal, There is another modal to be opened.

Because in the current behavior of my modal, the 3rd modal will be always in the back of the second modal. I already read this [article](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/window/how-to/opening-a-radwindow-from-within-a-radwindow) on how to get the parent modal, and it works perfectly for the second modal, but the problem is that the 3rd modal is not working properly.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change its z-index using CSS style. You could even assign one to each RadWindow.

```
<telerik:RadWindow ID="modalPopup" runat="server" Modal="true" Style="z-index: 100001;">
```